# vbs Msgbox parameter 262144

Tags: windows, vbscript

In the following example a message box will pop up with an icon to the left. and keep it on top of other windows.

```
msgbox("Text",vbSystemModal,"Title")
```

However the following will remove the icon and still keep it on top of the other windows like vbSystemModal.

```
msgbox("Text",262144,"Title")
```

Why is this? I can't find any documentation on this number or if it even has a name to it. Can anyone explain what exactly this number is doing?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in doubt see the documentation here for **[MsgBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx)**

Comment: Which doesn't mention anything about that number.

Comment: This what i mean this number where did you got it ? you can omit it and you will get the same result ? no ?

Comment: No, if you omit it, other windows can be on top of the message box. The number was found on an old inactive forum. So there are no answers there as to what it is.

Comment: I found it in autoitscript doc ==> https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MsgBox.htm